# Does the order of function calls matter in Firestore query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement pagination as explained in a web tutorial but I don't understand what is the order of functions in query for maximum speed. This is my code:

```
Query query = db.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .startAt("John").endAt("John" + "\uf8ff")
    .startAfter(lastVisible)
    .limit(10); //Called last
```

Or:

```
Query query = db.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .limit(10) // Called first
    .startAt("John").endAt("John" + "\uf8ff")
    .startAfter(lastVisible);
```

Or:

```
Query query = db.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .limit(10) // Called first
    .startAfter(lastVisible)
    .startAt("John").endAt("John" + "\uf8ff"); // Called last
```

All three compile fine, I have no error. How to make it correct for fast pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the perspective of performance, the order in which you build the Query object doesn't matter.  The end result is a Query with the same internal configuration.

However, startAt is not compatible with startAfter.  Only one or the other will take effect, likely the one that appears last in the builder chain.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson for your answer and I'd say that it's perfect that it's working this way. However, I saw a strange behavior though in case of the last query. Calling `.startAfter(lastVisible)` before `.startAt("John").endAt("John" + "\uf8ff")` makes the query return duplicate results. Is it normal?

Comment: Edited my answer.  It doesn't make sense to use both startAt and startAfter in the same query.  Where do you actually want to start the page?  This is not related to performance at all - it's a completely different issue.

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense? This is my scenario. I have a collection of contacts (>2500). And I want to paginate the results of a search because there are many "John" users.
Page1 has records from "JohnA" to "JohnB" where lastVisible is "JohnB". Page2 has records from "JohnC" to "JohnD" where lastVisible is :JohnD". Calling `.startAfter(lastVisible)` before `.startAt("John").endAt("John" + "\uf8ff")` return duplicate results and it make sense. It should be `.startAt("JohnD").endAt("JohnE" + "\uf8ff")` where lastVisible is "JohnD", right?

Comment: You should [pass a document snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#startAfter(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)) instead of the last value in that case.  That is an unambiguous pointer to the exact record, no matter how many duplicates there are of that field value.

Comment: I'm really confused now :( `lastVisible` is a `DocumentSnapshot` object as explained in the docs. In short, what I want is when I search for "John" to get all "John" users. As I paginate through the results, to keep the last `lastVisible` and get further till the. Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like your question started off about performance, but is actually just about how to paginate data correctly.  At this point, you should probably think about asking a new question that illustrates what's not working the way you expect, and ignore the issue of performance, as that's never really going to be an issue for Firestore queries.  Firestore doesn't perform queries that don't scale.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll ask another question. Thanks a ton!